# How to use dompdf in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, 3rd-party-library

I am trying to use dompdf in magento for printing invoice.

So I am trying to include dompdf in magento but its not working.

I used following code in `Mage.php` before `include_once "Varien/Autoload.php";`.

```
include_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
```

Its giving blank page.

Any help.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495704/magento-dompdf-autoloading-iisue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used code like

```
<?php
use Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Exception;

class Practice_ControllerTest_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
         require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

         $dompdf = new Dompdf();

         $dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

         $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

         $dompdf->render();

         $dompdf->stream();

     }
}
```

It works for me